# Obj-C - Facebook iOS SDK only available for Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to install the Facebook iOS SDK in my Obj-C project, but it appears as though the FacebookSDK is only written in Swift now? Anyone have any ideas or tips on how I can integrate the Facebook SDK with my Obj-C project? Installing via CocoaPods.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: From their documentation : "Using symbols now defined in Swift may require using @import syntax from Objective-C and using C++ will likely require workarounds like creating wrappers in Objective-C.", So either write yourself wrappers when they don't have one, or use a lower version of their pod.

Comment: Try downloading the (= 9.3.0) version of FBSDK. I use it and it supports Obj-C